# c++ : error: member access into incomplete type , unused parameter [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

I have the following code:

```
class MyNode;

class MyCompare {
  public:
    bool operator()(MyNode *a, MyNode *b) {
        return a->q <= b->q ? true : false;
    }
};

class MyNode {

  public:

    double sum;    
    double q;

    StateNode *parent;
    std::priority_queue<MyNode, std::vector<MyNode>, MyCompare> children;
};
```

But got the following compiling errors:

```
error: member access into incomplete type 'MyNode'
        return a->q <= b->q ? true : false;
                ^
..MyNode.h:35:7: note: forward declaration of 'MyNode'
class MyNode;
      ^
..MyNode.h:39:46: error: unused parameter 'b' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
    bool operator()(MyNode *a, MyNode *b) {
```

Any idea what I did wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Note that your comparer is incorrect as `comp(a, a)` should be `false` -> `return a->q < b->q;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message said, `a->q` and `b->q`, i.e. the usage of [class member access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) requires the type `MyNode` to be [complete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type). Only forward declaration is not sufficient.

> The following types are *incomplete types*:
>
> - class type that has been declared (e.g. by forward declaration) but not defined;

and

> Any of the following contexts requires class T to be complete:
>
> - class member access operator applied to an expression of type T;

You can move the definition of `operator()` after the definition of `MyNode`, at that point `MyNode` is complete. e.g.

```
class MyNode;

class MyCompare {
  public:
    bool operator()(const MyNode *a, const MyNode *b) const;
};

class MyNode {

  public:

    double sum;    
    double q;

    StateNode *parent;
    std::priority_queue<MyNode, std::vector<MyNode>, MyCompare> children;
};

bool MyCompare::operator()(const MyNode *a, const MyNode *b) const {
    return a->q < b->q;
}
```